# How to calculate an images aspect height/width

Tags: javascript

I have two variables with a height and width value, like so:

```
var height = 1080
var width = 1920
```

I know I'm about to get the ratio by doing `width/height` which gives me something like this: `1.7794253938832252`

The problem I'm having is I want to get the aspect height/width, ultimately I want to get `16:9` or `3:2` purely based on the height and width values of an image. I don't want to resize it, I just want to know what it should be based on the values of height and width.

How would I calculate this?

Comment: Well turn it into integers and work out the lowest common denominator. That one would be `17794253938832252:10000000000000000`, you can do the lowest common denominator bit (it's from GCSE level maths).

Comment: may be  (16/9- width/height)^2 :: (3/2-width/height)^2

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact your image will be either 16:9 or 3:2 (or some other standard aspect ratio) you could try to match your width and height with some presets in a switch statement. This is by far bulletproof, and might be too static.

**Update:** I added a default clause to catch ratios not defined, if needed.

```
var width = 1280;
var height = 720;
var aspectRatio;

switch (width/height) {
    case (16/9):
        aspectRatio = "16:9";
        break;
    case (3/2):
        aspectRatio = "3:2";
        break;
    default:
        aspectRatio = "Doesn't match any preset";
}

console.log(aspectRatio);
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the HCF(Highest Common Factor) between height and width, then divide height and width with HCF to get the ratio. See the following code.

```
function aspectRatio(width, height) {
var min = (height > width) ? width : height;
var ratioh = height;
var ratiow = width;
var hfc=0;
for(i=min;i>1;i--){
    if(height%i==0 && width%i==0){
        hfc=i;
        break;
    }
}
var aspectRatio = [];
aspectRatio['width'] = width/hfc;
aspectRatio['height'] = height/hfc;
return aspectRatio;
}

console.log(aspectRatio(1920,1080));
```

This function will take the width and heigh as parameter and will return the aspect ratio values.